# SWFUpload Progress Bar For Entire Queue

Tags: javascript, html, flash, swfupload

I have the SWFUpload progress bar working on a per file basis, but I would like a progress bar for the entire queue, so you can see your overall progress. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to handlers.js file and declare two global variables. This is just the idea to start with. You need to add some other code to check UploadError and Exception to reduce remainingFiles value.

```
var totalFiles = 0;
var remainingFiles = 0;
```

Update fileDialogComplete function as follow

```
function fileDialogComplete(numFilesSelected, numFilesQueued) {
    try {
        if (numFilesQueued > 0) {
            totalFiles = numFilesSelected;
            remainingFiles = totalFiles;
            this.startUpload();
            $("#progressbar").css({ 'display': '' });
        }
    } catch (ex) {
        this.debug(ex);
    }
}
```

In uploadProgress function, add this.

```
function uploadProgress(file, bytesLoaded) {
     if (percent === 100) {
           var uploadedFiles = totalFiles - remainingFiles;
           var uploadprogress = (uploadedFiles / totalFiles) * 100;
           $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: uploadprogress });
      }

}
```